# Costs of reading data in transaction on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am copying some data from sql server to firebird over the network. Because of integrity I need to use transactions, but I am transferring about 9k of rows. Has reading in opened transaction some negative influence on reading costs, against reading in non transaction mode?

Comment: All transactions impose a performance penalty. Are you looking for some exact numbers?

Comment: It would be interesting, if you have any. If you don't, I can test it also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED. It will lock the table for others while querying it.

MSDN on transaction isolation level:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

I've had the issue of an occasional strange error message concerning locking deadlock. This even happened to stackoverflow - see this great article by Jeff Atwood. I strongly recommend switching to 'read committed snapshot' which solved the error + my performance issues.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html

Answer (score 2):

"Non-Transaction mode" simply doesn't exists, there is always a transaction, whether you declare it or not. The question is really whether is there any difference between reading in an implicit transaction vs. reading in an explicit transaction. And the short answer is **no, there is no difference**.

There *may* be some difference if you use an explicit transaction under a higher isolation level, other than the default READ_COMMITTED. It also depends whether you do *anything else* in an explicit transaction, but all these details cannot be infered from the frugal information in your post.